Using a* algorithm without having distances
I have a list of nodes and all of their neighboring nodes. I am trying to get from node X to node Y in the shortest path using A*.
What heuristic should I use?

"I dont have the distances between the countys and i cant get them"? cant get them or not allowed to? datasets?

I wont have them in the question - I am looking for a huristic that does not include euclidean distance or manhatten distance.

"I wont have them in the question": what does that mean? US Counties are real-life entities. We know what they are, where they are,... Which "question" are you referring to here?

I am interested to know if there is a huristic for a* when all I have are the neighbors of each node(county).

If you cannot use the concept of real-life counties, then I would rephrase the question and not talk about states and counties at all. It is confusing. Just refer to a graph and nodes in the Euclidean plane, and nothing more.

If you only have the neighborhood relations and nothing else, then the only heuristic function available to you is h(X,Y) = 0. In this case, A* essentially becomes a Dijkstra search.
Note that in this setting your cost function also degrades to c(x,y) = 1, where x and y are neighbors. Consequently, you are better off running a breadth first search, because it doesn't need a priority queue like Dijkstra and A*, but can do away with a lifo queue, which is much faster.
